# Returning IDs for which an entire session matches criteria

Tags: sql, presto

My table, T, is like this

```
   id        event       category    request

    1        click           a          1
    2        click           b          2
    1        click           b          2
    1        cart_add                   3
    3        click           a          1
    3        card_add                   2
    3        purchase                   3
    2        click           c          1
    2        card_add                   3
    1        purchase                   4
```

and I want to return visitors who clicked category b products and added a category b product to their cart, as well as those who made a purchase after that. So, both people who added category b products and those who made category b product purchases.

My issue is basically querying the session. They're not generally in order, and the actual table I'm using is million of rows so ordering is very time consuming.

Is there a nice trick to find all ids which meet the above criteria, or is it easier to just do the analysis in R or Python? More specifically, from the table above, I'd return

```
purchased    added

    1          1
   null        2
```

Comment: How do you define what a session is?

Comment: just by the id in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` identifies a session.  This finds sessions that do all three:

```
select id
from t
where (event = 'click' and category = 'b') and
      (event = 'cart_add') and
      (event = 'purchase')
group by id
having count(distinct event) = 3;
```

If you need for the purchase to be later than the other two, then add:

```
max(case when event = 'purchase' then request end) > greatest(min(case when event = 'click' then request end), min(case when event = 'card_add' then request end))
```

Comment: So, this doesn't mean "when the event = 'cart_add' and the category = 'b' on the same row"? I've tried the where with multiple conditions and it returns nothing.

Comment: @Blake . . . according to your description, "cart_add" should have a category ("added a category b product to their cart").  According to the data, there is no such category.